# Using Math object to load 100% in loader bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, gsap

I am using Gsap and using TimelineLite Object for loader processing and showing percent content using Math.round object but it not showing accurate measure it show 67% percent instead of 100%
example

```
 ngOnInit() {
const timer = 4;
this.master =  new TimelineLite();
this.master.to(this.progress.nativeElement, timer, this.progressLoader(this.master));
this.master.to(this.panel.nativeElement, 2, this.verticalShow(this.master));
  }



progressLoader(obj: any) {
      let newPercent: any;
      this.count = this.count.nativeElement;
      const vars = {
      width: '100%',
      ease:  Power2.easeOut,
      onUpdate: () => {
        console.log(newPercent = Math.round((obj.progress() * 100)));
        this.count.innerHTML = newPercent + '%';
      }
    };
      return vars;
  }
```